# Want to make easy and simple paths to your webpages, heres how:

Tags: html, css

After making a website, it is always cool to have your pages accessable by users just typing `www.domain.com/myPage`

eg:

```
www.domain.com/home
www.domain.com/about
www.domain.com/contact
```

However, in reality, that may not work without correct structure, it may be:

```
www.domain.com/home.html
www.domain.com/about.html
www.domain.com/contact.html
```

To fix that, go to your main directory which may look like this:

```
index.html
about.html
contact.html
| assets
   | your files
```

But to fix it, every file needs to be in its own folder, and renamed to `index.html`
eg:

```
index.html
| about
   | index.html
| contact
   | index.html
| support
   | index.html

| assets
   | your files
```

Now, users can type `www.domain.com/contact` and be brought to that page etc

*Note: you may need to re-link old paths to files etc*

I hope that made your life easier! Have a good day

Comment: what do you mean by a "website extension"

Comment: One way to go is by creating a folder for each route you want, and placing an index.html in each folder, eg. create `your-web-root/home` and `your-web-root/home/index.html`

Comment: How you configure your web server or server-side program to handle URLs of that form depends on your choice of web server or server-side programming language/framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
summ.ga/
├── index.html
├── test.html
├── home/
│   ├─ index.html
│   ├─ bio/
│   │  └─ index.html
│   ├─ images/
│   │  └─ random.jpg
│   └─ styles/
└── static/
```

You need to understand how the folder structure and file extensions translate to URL strings. See the sample tree structure above. In short, create a `/home` directory and place an `index.html` inside. Should you want to automatically redirect `summ.ga` to `summ.ga/home/` you'd need to write a little bit of either server-side or client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to buy a domain first and add a page in HTML. After that you can name each page and get something like *sumn.gg/home*

.

Comment: Yea, I got *summ.ga* already, But if I name a file *home* it wont be a html file, it will have to be *index.html*. How can I make it so the domain changes that and makes it *summ.ga/home* rather than *summ.ga/index.html*?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have domain(summ.ga), it depends on what web server you use.

In the case of Tomcat, you can make it through modifying sever.xml

It is like this

```
<Context path="/home" docBase="docRoot"/>
```

And of course, there are more things to do.